# Change UIView Size for all application Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios

I added a bottom navigation bar view to the NavigationController, but now the bottom bar is over all the views from my app. I want to resize the views and rest the size of the bottom bar.

All my views are created programmatically, so i have something like this:

```
    public partial class myClass : MyController<myClassModel>
    {
            public override void LoadView()
            {
                base.LoadView();
                CreateControlsViews();
            }

            public override void ViewDidLoad()
            {
                base.ViewDidLoad();
                Binding();
                UpdateFramesView();
            }
    ...
```

And my Controller looks like this:

```
public class MyController : MvxViewController
{
    //public override void LoadView()
    //{
    //    base.LoadView();
    //    Can't override this, because some views has nib
    //}

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
          base.ViewDidLoad();
...
```

I tried something like this:

```
this.View.Frame = new CGRect(
   0,
   0,
   this.View.Bounds.Width,
   this.View.Bounds.Height - sizeBottomBar);
```

But only seems to work when i use on the LoadView, but that will destroy all the nib files. What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Was easier than i think, just need to add a new SafeArea.

```
this.AdditionalSafeAreaInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, aditionalSizeBar, 0);
```

Hope it can help anyone in a future!